# Java generics: solution of "Core Java" tutorial is not working on Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

I am reading the book "Core Java" by Hortsmann and Cornell (Vol.1).
In the Generics chapter, they suggest an input that is purposely wrong, in order to have a look at what the compiler says. My problem is: not only the compiler doesn't give me the same error, but it will keep on giving me errors also when I correct the input as stated in the book. Here's the deal:

```
public class PairTest1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double middle = ArrayAlg.getMiddle(3.14, 1729, 0);
    }
}

class ArrayAlg {
    public static <T> T getMiddle(T[] a) {
        return a[a.length / 2];
    }
}
```

The book says I should get the error:

> found: java.lang.Number&java.lang.Comparable>, required: double.

Instead, Eclipse won't let me run the program, saying

> The method getMiddle(T[]) in the type ArrayAlg is not applicable for
>   the arguments (double, int, int)

The book then says

> the remedy is to write all parameters as double values.

I therefore changed 1729 to 1729.1 and 0 to 0.1. Now Eclipse says:

> The method getMiddle(T[]) in the type ArrayAlg is not applicable for
>   the arguments (double, double, double)

Mmmhh... I didn't get what is going on. Suggestions?

Thank you & regards

EDIT: I tried to create the array `double[] doubles = { 3.14, 1729.1, 0.1 };` and to give it as parameter, but now I get the error `The method getMiddle(T[]) in the type ArrayAlg is not applicable for the arguments (double[])`

Comment: What version of the JDK is the book using? What version are you using? Does the book use Eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change your call to

```
double middle = ArrayAlg.getMiddle(new Double[]{ 3.14, 1729.0, 0.0 });
```

If you want to pass them the way you are doing, then you should change the declaration to

```
public static <T> T getMiddle(T... a)
{
    return a[a.length / 2];
}
```

using the var-arg syntax of Java. Then you can call the method as

```
double middle = ArrayAlg.getMiddle(3.14, 1729.0, 0.0);
```

Comment: great, it works! :) one more question: I tried to change what I did in my edit, using "Double[] doubles" instead of "double[] doubles". Like this, it worked. does it mean that I always have to use the Wrappers when using generics on primitive types?

Comment: you should be able to use a call like getMiddle(3.14d, 1729.0d, 0.0d);

Comment: Yes, you have to use wrappers if you are using arrays because an array of primitive type is not auto-boxed to an array of corresponding wrapper class.

Answer (score 4):

The function expects an array, but you are passing 3 individual double parameters instead.